# bootstrap-add-clear hideOnBlur set toTrue stops plugin from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

```html
$("input").addClear({
  hideOnBlur: true
});
```

I'd like for the clear icon to be only visible if the input is in focus. According to the documentation, this should solve my issue. However, technically, clicking on the icon can only happen when the input is "onBlur". So before the click handler loads, the icon disappears.

Any bit of direction helps. Thanks!

Comment: is it supposed to be :input ? or is that a typo ? im guessing its a typo

Comment: @redsecurity Oh! I just copied the sample from their documentation. I'm actually using a class to grab my input.